# List files that match but with any extension

Tags: shell-script, find

Given a file with path

```
/foo/bar/a.b.c.d.x
```

I would like to be able to find all files matching /foo/bar/a.b.c.d.* with any final extension

This is what I have been using thus far

```
findSiblingFiles () {
  local filePath="$1"
  find "$(dirname "$filePath")" -name "$(basename "${filePath%.*}").*"
}
```

This works most of the time, but it breaks if the file contains square brackets (eg "a.b.c.[helloworld].x").  I can get it to work if I backslash escape the square brackets, but to do that in a function I would have to add the backslashes with regexes, which is getting into messy territory and I wonder if I'm missing a more simple way to do this.

Ideally it should find files with *any* characters in the file name (brackets, braces, parens, etc), and time efficiency is a consideration.

Comment: `filePath='a.b.c.[helloworld].x' && basename "${filePath%.*}"` outputs `a.b.c.[helloworld]` - so if it's wrong then what did you expect?

Comment: Ah, you mean you want to escape pattern special characters in `find`?

Comment: I don't specifically want to use `find` although that's my current approach.  I'm looking for a general (and not overly convoluted) way to find files in the same folder with alternate extensions, that doesn't choke on square brackets (or other characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see all files that matches the pattern `/foo/bar/a.b.c.d.*`, use

```bsh
printf '%s\n' /foo/bar/a.b.c.d.*
```

To see all files that matches the pattern `/foo/bar/a.b.c.[helloworld].*`, where `[hellowerld]` is literal, use

```bsh
printf '%s\n' /foo/bar/a.b.c.'[helloworld]'.*
```

I.e., quote the parts of the pattern that need to be literal.

If you get the string `a.b.c.[helloworld].x` and you want to see all files under `/foo/bar` that matches the pattern that you get if you remove the last `.x` and replace it with `.*`, use

```bsh
string='a.b.c.[helloworld].x'
printf '%s\n' /foo/bar/"${string%.*}".*
```

The only thing you need to think about here is to quote the expansion of the variable substitution.

Would you want to do this in the `bash` shell, recursively, and include hidden names, then use

```bsh
shopt -s globstar dotglob
string='a.b.c.[helloworld].x'
printf '%s\n' /foo/bar/**/"${string%.*}".*
```

Your function could probably be written (without searching in subdirectories) as

```bsh
findSiblingFiles () {
    printf '%s\n' "${1%.*}".*
}
```

or, to have it output nothing, not even a blank line, if the pattern does not match,

```bsh
findSiblingFiles () (
    shopt -s nullglob
    set -- "${1%.*}".*
    [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && printf '%s\n' "$@"
)
```

Note that since we are only modifying the first argument's "tail", we don't need to separate the filename from the directory path, unless we want to verify that there's actually a dot in the given filename, which the following code does.

```bsh
findSiblingFiles () (
    shopt -s nullglob

    if [[ ${1##*/} != *.* ]]; then
        echo 'Filename has no suffix' >&2
        return 1
    fi

    set -- "${1%.*}".*

    [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && printf '%s\n' "$@"
)
```

Testing:

```
$ findSiblingFiles ~myself/local/src/project/doc/document.txt
/home/myself/local/src/project/doc/document.man
/home/myself/local/src/project/doc/document.mdoc
/home/myself/local/src/project/doc/document.txt
```

Comment: Very clean, thank you.  For the record one tweak I will make is to handle the case of inputting a non existent file path (where the literal .* would come out after the input) by catching the result and checking it via `[[ "${result: -2}" == $'.*' ]] && return` to output nothing, and only print the result after that check.

Comment: @user1169420 See updated answer with extra function added.

Comment: Or with `zsh`: `findSiblingFiles() print -rC1 -- $1:r.*(N)`. Or `findSiblingFiles() { set -o localoptions -o extendedglob; print -rC1 -- $1:r.[^.]##~$1(N); }` to exclude the file itself and exclude `<rootname>.foo.bar`

Comment: Note that difference in behaviour with csh / zsh's `:r` (root name) compared to `${1%.*}` when `$1` is `foo.d/bar` for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the heads-up about that. This was now fixed by parsing out the filename and checking it for dots first.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
filesWithSameRootName() {
  set -o localoptions -o extendedglob
  local filepath=${1%%/#}
  print -rC1 -- $filepath:h/**/$filepath:r(|[^.]#)(ND)
}
```

`$filepath:r` like in csh or vim (or `bash` but only for history expansion) returns the *root* of a path, that is the filepath stripped of its extension. For `dir.d/file.foo.bar`, that's `dir.d/file.foo` and for `dir.d/file`, that's `dir.d/file` (and `dir.d/` for `dir.d/`, hence the stripping of trailing `/`s first above).

So to find the files with the same *root*, we find (recursively with `**/`) the files with an optional `.<zero-or-more-non-dots>` appended to them.

All the name-matching predicates in `find` (`-name`, `-path`, `-regex`...) take a pattern as argument (either shell wildcard or regex), so for a substring match, you'd need to escape the regexp operators in there. Or you could post-process the `find -print0` (or POSIXly: `find -exec printf '%s\0' {} +`) output with something that can do basic string comparison, like using POSIX `sh` syntax and `perl`:

```
filesWithSameRootName() {
  find "$(dirname -- "$1")" -exec printf '%s\0' {} + |
    FILE="$1" perl -l -0ne '
      BEGIN{
        $root = $ENV{FILE};
        $root =~ s{.*/}{};
        $root =~ s{\.[^./]*\Z}{};
      }
      print if m{/\Q$root\E(\.[^.]*)?\Z}'
}
```

(though without the sorting done by `zsh` globs, and assuming the dirname doesn't end in newline characters and doesn't start with `-` and is not `!` / `(`, `)`...)